# Property of undefined error goes away on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

Upon start of my project I get an error stating `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ActionType' of undefined` this only happens when I open the project for the first time. When I refresh the page the error goes away and does not come back.

```
const details = {
 ActionType: currentData.ActionType,
 RequestedByName: currentData.RequestedByName
}
```

```
{
            name: "",
            label: "",
            options: {
                filter: false,
                sort: false,
                customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => {
                       const currentData= opt [
                            tableMeta.rowIndex
                        ];
                        const details = {
                            ActionType: currentData.ActionType,
                            RequestedByName: currentData.RequestedByName
                        }
                    return (
                        currentData.ActionTypeID === 0 || currentData.ActionCompletedByID > 0 ? null :
                        <Icon>
                        <Modal
                        details = {details}>
                    </Modal>
                    </Icon> 
                        )
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of the `opt` array, specifically, `opt[tableMeta.rowIndex]` (either add a `console.log` or a breakpoint). Chances are that value is `undefined` the first time you access the page, and therefore accessing a property on it causes an error.

I suggest adding an `if(currentData)...` condition, before assigning to `details`.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the first time it is happening your data is still undefined but after that its cached so your results are fine - try short circuiting this by using a ternary such as `ActionType: currentData ? currentData.ActionType : []`